# Compile vim with clipboard and xterm

Tags: vim, clipboard

I want to compile the current version of vim with:

```
+clipboard +xterm_clipboard and ruby support
```

But every time I compile it the `clipboard` and the `xterm_clipboard` options aren't enabled.

Is there a lib needed or must I add any other options in the configuration step?

```
./configure \
--enable-rubyinterp=dynamic \
--enable-cscope \
--enable-gui=auto \
--enable-gtk2-check \
--enable-gnome-check \
--with-features=huge \
--with-x 
 make && sudo make install
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can see if `configure` manage to find a working X lib by checking the output of (or scroll through the output of `configure` in your terminal):

```
$ grep X11 src/auto/config.h
#define HAVE_X11
```

If `configure` failed then you'll see:

```
$ grep X11 src/auto/config.h
/* #undef HAVE_X11 */
```

You'll need to install the appropriate X development library like `xlib` and `xtst` for `--with-x` to work.

On ubuntu it should be enough to install `libx11-dev` and `libxtst-dev`.

Comment: Only installing those two libs on Ubuntu 12.04 didn't work for me. You can try installing the xorg-dev package under Ubuntu, although you do get a lot of additional and potentially unneeded packages this way.

Comment: Running `sudo aptitude install vim-gnome` for 12.04 also fixes this.

Comment: Exact X.Org packages seem to be: `libx11-dev libxtst-dev libxt-dev libsm-dev libxpm-dev` That gets all the HAVE_X11 defines except HAVE_X11_XMU_EDITRES_H, which doesn't seem to be enabled by X11/Xmu/Editres.h being added by libxmu-dev, probably only used in gvim.

Comment: @holygeek, please add all packages listed by Simon in your answer as they all appear necessary on Ubuntu. Took me forever to see Simon's comment and actually get the clipboard working. Thanks!

Comment: @holygeek `grep: src/auto/config.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: This didn't work for me until I completely deleted my vim directory and started over.

Comment: @ZaneHitchcox same issue for me, it seems you can disable this "configure" cache behaviour by `./configure --cache-file=/dev/null` THIS however had absolutely no effect for me and I had to do `rm src/auto/config.cache` .. This however is much easier by running `make distclean` which removes this cache of configure, but it wasn't obvious coming back to this after a while.

Comment: On Fedora: sudo yum install libX11-devel libXtst-devel libXt-devel libSM-devel libXpm-devel.

Answer (score 6):

ubuntu18.04.4

> sudo apt install libx11-dev libxtst-dev libxt-dev libsm-dev libxpm-dev
>
> ./configure --enable-python3interp=dynamic --prefix=$HOME/.local --enable-rubyinterp=dynamic --enable-gtk2-check --enable-gnome-check --with-features=huge --with-x
>
> make install
>
> ./src/vim ---version | grep clip

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't install python3